# Omitting the standalone attribute in xml declaration when using Java DOM + Transformer.

Tags: java, xml, dom

Is there any way to tell the Transformer (when serializing an XML document using DOM), to omit the standalone attribute?

Preferably without using a hack, i.e. ommitting the whole XML declaration and then prepending it manually.

My current code:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes"); //Note nothing is changed

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
transformer.transform(source, result);
 return result.getWriter().toString();
```

Current:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<someElement/>
```

Intended:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<someElement/>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Figured it out..

Instead of changes to the transformer,

I add the following to the document object.

```
  document.setXmlStandalone(true);
```

Comment: Why does that even work? According to the spec:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#sec-rmd
"If there are external markup declarations but there is no standalone document declaration, the value "no" is assumed."
This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578645/what-does-the-standalone-directive-mean-in-xml also states that if standalone attribute is missing then "no" is assumed. Then how come document.setXmlStandalone(true); removes the attribute?

Answer (score 3):

`document.setXmlStandalone(true/false);` is working OK.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a combination of:

`doc.setXmlStandalone(true);`

and

`transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes"); // this is used to show the standalone tag`

Comment: Finally a valid answer! :D

Comment: The goal is to hide the attribute, the above answer shows the attribute.

Comment: @pkozuchowski you're correct, but what I'm saying is that we need to set both options to get it working properly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. How do you omit the standalone= attribute in the xml declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Which Java version are you using and/or which XSLT transformer? With Sun Java 1.6.0_16, the standalone attribute is only set in the output document if you set the output property and the content is also correct.

Comment: I get the same problem using the built-in Java 8 SE from Eclipse 4.5 (Mars).