# Can't get RSS formatted with XSL-stylesheet to work in Chrome

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, rss, podcast

I've seen a great example of how to format an RSS podcast file in a Chrome browser using an XSL-template: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p002w6r2/episodes/downloads.rss.

I want to get the same with my podcast file, but I just can't get it to work. It always just displays the RSS file, but does not format it.

Would anyone who knows this stuff be able to take a look and tell me what I do wrong?

My RSS is here: http://fietsrapport.be/gijs/thenetworkeffect2.rss, the template is same file with `.xsl` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tested both with [PaleMoon](http://www.palemoon.org/)(a Firefox fork), and they both work well. I know Chrome has some tight security restrictions on applying XSLT-transformation to XML-content. Whyever...

So I try to annotate some differences between the BBC approach and yours:

- Your XML has the [`standalone`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14690849/1305969) attribute on its `<?xml ...` processing instruction. I don't know if that matters, but the differences of the browsers regarding security restrictions applied to XML-XSLT are tremendous.
- The path of the XSLT given in the `href` of the `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ...` directive is relative for BBC and absolute for your site. *This is very important.* BBC has `href="/programmes/downloads.xsl"` and you have `href="http://fietsrapport.be/gijs/thenetworkeffect.xsl"`. Cross-domain XSLT appliance is often blocked for security reasons. So maybe the URL is not recognized to be on your domain?
- If you have a script blocker like `NoScript` active, it would surely block XML-XSLT-transformation, so you should disable it on your domain.

The rest of the RSS/XML looks pretty much isomorphic, so nothing to comment here. Hope this helps. So the best guess would be to change the path from absolute to relative.